# Array / TextJoin

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, textjoin

I have this table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Kelly | 0530,0630,1730 |
| Mark | 0830,1630,1530 |
| Jenn | 0530,0630,1630 |

I am trying to find a formula that will return all the people from column A that have 0530 in column B. So my output in a single cell would be Kelly, Jenn.  I've tried several things on my own, but nothing seems to be working.  Can anyone help?

I've tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF(D2:D8="0530",C2:C8,"no")))
```

but everything is a "no" because the cells don't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "0530")=TRUE))
```

[image]

`Filter` `A` column if `B` column matches `"0530"` and join the result with `textjoin` ignore_empty set to `1`.

Used formulas help
[**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`FILTER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) - [**`REGEXMATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(SPLIT(B2:B4, ",")=530, A2:A4, )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try (simply):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("0530", $B:$B)), $A:$A, ""))
```

[image]